# Как, используя C#, получить Код устройства из Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

Если зайти в "О программе" в Windows 10, то можно обнаружить параметр Код устройства. Он выглядит как-то так E85AB3BF-3CBD-4164-BB8C-CА1C1EA9BD8C.

PS. Код продукта это SerialNumber в Win32_OperatingSystem. Он не интересен.

Comment: В реестре искали? _Он выглядит как-то так_ - выглядит как GUID.

Comment: Искал, в реестре такого значения - нет. Среди ID устройств тоже. Реально не пойму, что это за значение.

Comment: Я откатил состояние вопроса к предыдущей версии. Не пишите ответ в сам вопрос. Если вы хотите поделиться собственным решением, опубликуйте его ответом. Так же не забудьте отметить наиболее полезный ответ принятым. [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Есть кто живой? Вы можете поставить зеленую галочку слева от ответа, чтобы отметить его принятым.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@aepot - прав.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SQMClient - MachineId
```

Получить можно так

```cs
using Microsoft.Win32;
```

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string path = Path.Combine(Registry.LocalMachine.Name, @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SQMClient");
    Guid MachineId = new Guid((string)Registry.GetValue(path, "MachineId", null));
    Console.WriteLine(MachineId);
}
```

`System.Guid` - родной формат для хранения такого типа данных. Для вывода в строку можно применять различное форматирование, варианты форматирования показаны в документации - [Guid.ToString()](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.guid.tostring?view=net-5.0).

Comment: Действительно. А поиск по точному совпадению ничего не дал.